# Indexing with join queries MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

I'm fairly new to SQL and I'm trying to understand indexing. Please help if you can!

I'm using MySQL 8.0 along with a join query and indexing on those tables. I have two tables charitable and Metro, with over 1.5 M and 7000 records which I'm trying to index and apply a join on.

**Note**: I already have a primary key for both of these tables.

```
create table charitable (
EIN bigint primary key not null,
NAME Varchar(255) not null,
ICO varchar(255) null,
STREET varchar(255) not null,
CITY varchar(255) not null,
STATE varchar(255) not null,
ZIP varchar(255) not null, 
GROUP_NO int not null,
SUBSECTION Int not null,
AFFILIATION Int not null,
CLASSIFICATION Int not null,
RULING int not null,
DEDUCTIBILITY Int not null,
FOUNDATION Int not null,
ACTIVITY bigint not null,
ORGANIZATION Int not null,
STATUS Int not null,
TAX_PERIOD varchar(255) null,
ASSET_CD Int not null,
INCOME_CD int not null,
FILING_REQ_CD int not null,
PF_FILING_REQ_CD int not null,
ACCT_PD int not null,
ASSET_AMT varchar(255) null,
INCOME_AMT varchar(255) null,
REVENUE_AMT varchar(255) null,
NTEE_CD varchar(255) null,
SORT_NAME varchar(255) null
);`

create table Metro(
City varchar(255) not null,
State varchar(255) not null,
MMSA varchar(255) null,
MMSA_type varchar(255) null,
CBSA varchar(255) null,
city_St varchar(255) not null,
metro_city varchar(255) null,
primary key (City, State)
);
```

Here is the query.

```
select co.name, mc.Metro from charitable as co
join Metro as mc
on co.city=mc.city and co.state = mc.state;
```

So, I applied unique indexing on the Metro(state,city) and simple indexing on the charitable(state) which happen to be used in the Join statement.

This indexing has helped reduce the fetch performance from 18.047 seconds to 17.85 seconds. But, I do not understand how the **indexing works on the duplicate values** from the charitable. For example, the charitable table has over 5000 duplicate records for a (state, city) combination. And, the second doubt is how does the **indexing work along with the join query?**

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `EXPLAIN {query}` shows what decisions where made. A `city,state` secondary index on `charitable` will help. Examine `EXPLAIN` before and after that index is made. Offical docs on [How MySQL (8.0) uses indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Probably Metro's `PRIMARY KEY(City, State)` will be used for the `JOIN`.  Adding `INDEX(city, state,  name)` for `charitable` may help by being "covering".

Use reasonable values, not 255 blindly.

Don't use `VARCHAR` for amounts; arithmetic and comparisons won't work well.

Since you are fetching 1.5M rows, you should not expect it to be very fast.

If that is not the complete `SELECT`, then this is not the complete answer.